# TCP Message Framing?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I'm trying to implement framing into my networking library. I feel like I've done it correctly with length prefixing 4 bytes at the start, but its only ever reading the first 4 characters?

Output:

```
Message Length: 4
Message: {"Cl
```

I've written this class to wrap it on sending:

```
public class FramingProtocol
{
    public static byte[] WrapMessage(byte[] message)
    {
        var lengthPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length);
        var all = new byte[lengthPrefix.Length + message.Length];

        lengthPrefix.CopyTo(all, 0);
        message.CopyTo(all, lengthPrefix.Length);

        return all;
    }
}
```

And then overriding Write method here:

```
public async Task WriteAsync(byte[] data)
{
    var framedData = FramingProtocol.WrapMessage(data);
    await _client.GetStream().WriteAsync(framedData);
}
```

Now on receiving is where I'm a bit hazy, I have this, although I'm unsure if I'm reading it all back correctly.

```
private async Task StartListeningAsync()
{
    while (_client.Connected)
    {
        await ReceiveAsync();
    }
}

public async Task ReceiveAsync()
{
    var messageLengthByte = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    var messageLength = await _client.GetStream().ReadAsync(messageLengthByte, 0, messageLengthByte.Length);

    if (messageLength == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Message Length: {messageLength}");

    var buffer = new byte[messageLength];
    var bytesRead = 0;

    while (bytesRead < messageLength)
    {
        bytesRead += await _client.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, bytesRead, messageLength - bytesRead);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer)}");
    
    OnReceived(buffer);
}

private void OnReceived(byte[] bytesReceived)
{
    var content = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytesReceived);

    if (content == "PONG")
    {
        LastPong = DateTime.Now;
        return;
    }

    var args = new AppControlApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs
    {
        Content = content
    };
    
    MessageReceivedAsync?.Invoke(args);
}
```

Comment: `buffer.Length < messageLength` this is always false, because they are always equivalent. You don't have to handle reading blocks yourself, the client class will do the work. And what's `_buffer`? It looks like a typo.

Comment: Thank you, I was incorrectly using the old property and assuming length related only to the bytes read. I've edited it.

Comment: You were still reading only 4 bytes, you should get the length with `BitConverter.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 0):

`messageLength` is just the size of the length *value* ie 4 bytes. Instead you need to convert it to an `int` value from the bytes. You also need to use `ReadExactlyAsync` to perfectly fill the buffer.

```cs
public async Task ReceiveAsync()
{
    var messageLengthByte = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    try
    {
        await _client.GetStream().ReadExactlyAsync(messageLengthByte);
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException)
    {
        return;
    }

    var messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(messageLengthByte);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message Length: {messageLength}");
    if (messageLength == 0)
        return;
    
    var buffer = new byte[messageLength];
    await _client.GetStream().ReadExactlyAsync(buffer);
    var content = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {content}");
    
    OnReceived(content);
}
```

You could further improve this by caching arrays in static fields or using an ArrayPool. Also instead of wrapping the whole array in another one for the Write, you could just write the four byte length.

```cs
byte[] _lengthArray = new byte[4];

public async Task WriteAsync(byte[] data)
{
    var stream = _client.GetStream();
    BitConverter.TryWriteBytes(_lengthArray, data.Length);
    await stream.WriteAsync(_lengthArray);
    await stream.WriteAsync(framedData);
}
```

```cs
byte[] _messageLengthByte = new byte[4];

public async Task ReceiveAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await _client.GetStream().ReadExactlyAsync(messageLengthByte);
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException)
    {
        return;
    }

    var messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(messageLengthByte);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message Length: {messageLength}");
    if (messageLength == 0)
        return;
    
    var buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(messageLength);
    await _client.GetStream().ReadExactlyAsync(buffer);
    var content = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);

    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {content}");    
    OnReceived(content);
}
```

Consider also using the new `Utf8String` to reinterpret the array as a UTF8 string, alternatively use another `ArrayPool<char>`. Consider using `CancellationToken` in various places to make this whole thing easily cancellable. I hope you are disposing your stream properly.

Comment: Thank you for writing this. Just one thing before I try applying it, `ReadExactlyAsync` doesn't return a int but a value task, so what should bytesRead actually be set to?

Comment: You need to `await` it as shown, and yeah it just throws if you don't have enough bytes so catch the exception and return